# How to remove cursor from middle of magnifier tool view?

Tags: preview, mouse

Im on a MacBook Pro , monterey 12.6.6 using the Preview program.  When using the magnifier under Tools I cant get the cursor from blocking what im magnifying. How do I get the cursor out of the tool window??  In my screenshot below you can see the ' C ' im magnifying and the cursor in the middle.  Id like the cursor to not be there so when I move the tool around, the view is magnified and unobstructed.

[image]

Another example with an older MBP.

[image]

Comment: It should vanish as you enter the box. Try dragging the cursor up to the menu bar, then back down into the box again.

Comment: Have you tried simply clicking on the "Hide Cursor" button located on the tool bar, or using the keyboard shortcut "Command + Shift + H"?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "as I enter the box" ?  When I select use magnifier, the circle appears and my cursor is automatically in it and moves in the middle of the circle as I move the magnifier.  I cant make it go away.

Comment: I dont see "hide cursor" anywhere...  im assuming you mean the tool bar right above the keyboard?  I did try the shortcut "cmd + shft +H " and nothing changes.  Its not in the Tools menu in Preview either.

Comment: I don't know how you're generating that tiny round 'view' [I actually thought that was a 'click indicator' just for the picture]. The magnifier is a big rectangular box - just tested on a couple of Macs & it's the same on Ventura as it was on Mojave. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuZur.jpg

Comment: no clue. mine has always been a circle.  also is expandable to make the magnified area bigger.  OEM.  No add ons....

Comment: Are you looking at the Zoom Option or in Preview, Tools , Show Magnifier?  I just watched a video re: Zoom, and its a box shape.  Ive never used that and my magnifier has always been a circle.

Comment: I have another MBP, 2013, and its shows a circle too.  Ill post a screenshot above.

Comment: So, I tried another .jpeg image like the stamp one above on the older MBP and there is no cursor in the circle.  BUT, its still a circle.  Still trying to get rid of the cursor on mine so it doesnt obstruct the view of whats being magnified

Comment: So im not sure why this works - but in Preview under Tools, if I select "Rectangular Selection" instead of whats checked by default, "Automatic Selection", they choose Magnifier, the cursor disappears.  However, it reverts back to Automatic after each use

Answer (score 0):

So im not sure why this works - but in Preview under Tools, if I select "Rectangular Selection" instead of whats checked by default, "Automatic Selection", they choose Magnifier, the cursor disappears. However, it reverts back to Automatic after each use